# need help to define different sonar threshold

Tags: sonarqube

I have a very large java project which is divided into 4 different modules 1,2,3 and 4. Each module has individual Hudson job and integrated with sonar as well.

Is there any way to define different threshold for each module and allow hudson build to fail for each module if threshold is greater than the defined threshold?

All the help is really appreciated. Looking for some efficient way.

Thanks,
Sanjiv

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible unless each module is analyzed separately as an application. Note that you can use the Views plugin then to aggregate the modules: http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/portfolio-management/

Comment: Yes I want to analyze separateky for each module. Each module has different Hudson job and if threshold for that module is higher than the defined one build should fail.